# Significados del verbo "camellar"

Tags: gramática, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, colombia

> Voy a camellar mañana.

Alguien me dijo que ese verbo era algo sexual y él era de Colombia.

Comment: Es posible, pero al menos el Diccionario de Americanismos no recoge ninguna acepción que parezca sexual (significa en Colombia, según ese y el DRAE, trabajar de forma continuada o ardua).  Tampoco encuentro dicho significado en diccionarios de carácter abierto.  A ver qué nos dicen un colombiano.

Comment: Nunca he oído ese verbo en España, a no ser que se refiera a "camelar" que uno de sus signicados es seducir.

Comment: Con "otros significados" das por sentado que ya hay algún significado que todos conocemos. A mí no me suena ninguno. ¿Puedes [edit]ar la pregunta para dar más detalles? Algo más de contexto y explicación puede ser muy útil para que la comunidad sepa a qué te refieres.

Comment: Veo que [la definición del DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6x1Dd0c) indica _
1. intr. Col., C. Rica, El Salv. y Hond. Trabajar arduamente._

Comment: Perfectamente puedo decir "_voy a trabajar (camellar)_" con sentido sexual, si se dan las condiciones y tal vez con alguna entonación o mirada especial. No sería idiomático, sino simplemente uso metafórico de las palabras. Y así casi cualquier cosa: "mañana me toca", "mañana tengo que dar clases", "mañana es día de pago", "mañana tengo visita médica", tus amigotes te entenderían.

Answer (score 4):

El verbo *Camellar* y el sustantivo "Camello" son bastante comunes en Colombia y significan "Trabajar"/"Trabajo".

No tienen absolutamente ningún significado sexual.

Lo puedes escuchar en frases como:

> Voy a camellar = voy a trabajar.
>
> Voy para el camello = voy para el trabajo
>
> Que camello tan verraco = que trabajo tan duro (verraco es otro Colombianismo algunas veces escrito berraco {hay largas discusiones al respecto})
>
> ¿Cómo va el camello? = ¿Cómo va tu trabajo?

Cuando estés en Colombia o hables con un Colombiano en una conversación informal, lo puedes usar sin ningún temor.

Comment: Para el que este interesado en verraco/berraco http://www.elespectador.com/impreso/opinion/gazapera/articuloimpreso-el-berraco es uno de los enlaces entre muchos que puede consultar.

Answer (score 2):

No , is not sexual expression.
No , no es nada sexual .
*camellar* is similar to work,
Example:

> What are you doing , I'm working

is similar to saying:

> ¿Que haces? , Camellando.

Es una palabra muy usada en Colombia , sin embargo no la recomiendo usar en entornos formales.